# Why can't MariaDB 10.4.8 (latest version) change this column type?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
MariaDB [myDatabase]> alter table myTable MODIFY Descr varchar(255) default '' not null CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci' at line 1
```

Why is this failing? The syntax is correct, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` are part of the datatype specification, so they have to be directly after `VARCHAR(255)`, you can't put the `DEFAULT` and `NOT NULL` attributes in the middle.

```
alter table myTable MODIFY Descr varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci not null default '';
```